# Unable to write on directory that allowed by setfacl

Tags: centos, permissions, acl

I add permission to work on a directory as following:

```
Udi> setfacl -R -m d:u:sami:rwx tmp

Udi> getfacl tmp/
# file: tmp/
# owner: udi
# group: udi
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:sami:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

Udi> ls -ld tmp/
drwxr-sr-x+ 2 udi udi 6 2017-10-31 18:47 tmp//
```

Now, when Sam try to write in the directory
he gets an error message:

```
Sami> cd ~udi/tmp
Sami> mkdir abc
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: Permission denied
```

I tried to figure out the problem by looking at the logs of
Selinux  with out success, there is no avc about it
and no sign in other logs.

The OS is Centos 7  and the filesystem is  xfs

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `-m d:u:sami:rwx` changes the default permissions only i.e. the permissions for newly created objects in this directory. It does not affect the permissions of that directory at all. You need a second call:

```
setfacl -R -m u:sami:rwx tmp
```

Comment: Thanks Hauke,  Now I know that to set default ACL I must do it in two steps:  own for setting the participants and two for the defaults.